# How to convert a Varchar2 value into a number in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck in my database systems assignments and I would like some help here. I am implementing a database for a Netflix like platform and have a column called **Duration** which stores the duration of each movie/show in the following format:

[image]

I wanted to get the average duration of the shows/movies that are listed in the database.

**Is there any method to convert "93 mins" to 93 as a number so that the average of the column could be calculated?**

This is the schema for the table that has duration as a column:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `SUBSTR`ing up until the first space character and then convert it using `TO_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( duration, 1, INSTR( duration, ' ' ) -1 ) )
FROM   details;
```

or, you can use a regular expression to get the substring of just the leading digits:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( duration, '^\d+' ) )
FROM   details;
```

However, the best solution would be to stop using a `VARCHAR2` data type and, instead, use a `NUMBER` column then you do not need to do the conversion and are storing numeric data in an appropriate data type rather than as a string. If you want to display the value with the units then perform that formatting when you need it.

Comment: yes I get your point but the data set is given and we're not allowed to change it. So gotta adjust to this :)
Thank you so much!

Comment: I would ask the instructor about the design flaw of using a character data type for data that is inherently numeric.